# Unpacking tuples variadic template arguments

Tags: c++

I would like to unpack a tuple of variadic types and forward the args to the correct class?

```
class IntegerField(){
  public:
    IntegerField(int i){}
};
class StringField(){
   public:
      StringField(std::string s){}
};
class Person{
 public:
    IntegerField id(){ return mId; }
    StringField name() { return mName; }
 private:
  IntegerField mId;
  StringField mName;
};

template<typename... Types>
  void createField(Types... args){
     // want to create IntegerField or StringField and pass the args "42" or "Joe" respectively
     // exand the line to something like
     // std::make_unique<IntegerField>(42) 
     // ...
     auto uPtr = std::make_unique<Types...>(std::forward<Types...>(args)...);  // # ???
}

int main(){
   using IF = std::tuple<IntegerField, int>;
   using SF = std::tuple<StringField, std::string>;

   Person person;

   createField<IF, SF>({person.id(), 42},{person.name(), "Joe"});
}
```

Comment: What do you want type of the `uPtr` to be ? Will it be `std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<IntegerField> , std::unique_ptr<StringField>>` ?

Comment: @arnes - I would like it to be std::unique_ptr<IntegerField> or std::unique_ptr<StringField> depending on the args passed.

Comment: In your example, you are passing both of them, so the `uPtr` should express both IntegerField and StringField somehow. But I suppose you want to specialize for the types individually ?

Comment: @arnes, sure, I would like to specialize individually. I thought the args will be unpacked individually (each tuple argument)? please expound more on this

Comment: I shared an example. Could you look at https://godbolt.org/z/L4b9An   . Result is stored in tuple again

Comment: @arnes, Great!, however, the code has is not compiling, it has some linker errors

Comment: @arnes, fixed it, now it is compiling!

Comment: I did it intentionally to make compiler to print the typename. You're welcome. So is this what you asked ?

Comment: @arnes, I think this will suffice, I will restructure the code to suite my needs. Thank you very much. Could you copy the code to the answer section so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I adapted the answer a bit so you do not need to provide manual overloads: https://godbolt.org/z/TzRXZH

Comment: @n314159's suggestion is better, you should accept his answer if he posts.

Comment: @n314159, Wow! very very nice, If not much to ask, could you explain, and please post as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based very heavily on @arnes work:

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility> // For std::index_sequence_for

class IntegerField{
  public:
    IntegerField(int i){}
};
class StringField{
   public:
      StringField(std::string s){}
};
class Person{
 public:
    Person() : mId { 5 } , mName { "empty" } {}
    IntegerField id(){ return mId; }
    StringField name() { return mName; }
 private:
    IntegerField mId;
    StringField mName;
};

namespace detail {
    template<class Field, class... Args, std::size_t... Indices>
    auto create(const std::tuple<Field, Args...>& t, std::index_sequence<Indices...> seq) {
        return std::make_unique<Field>(std::get<Indices + 1>(t)...);
    }
}

template<class Field, class... Args>
auto create(const std::tuple<Field, Args...>& t) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Field, Args...>, std::unique_ptr<Field>> {
    return detail::create(t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}


template<typename... Types>
void createField(Types... args){
    auto res = std::make_tuple( create( std::forward<Types>( args ) )... );
}

int main(){
   using IF = std::tuple<IntegerField, int>;
   using SF = std::tuple<StringField, std::string>;

   Person person;

   createField<IF, SF>({person.id(), 42},{person.name(), "Joe"});
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TzRXZH)